# Date format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am changing date format using below code, however when I extracting this dataframe in excel, this date is appearing in text format (not date format).

```
new_data['Expiry']=new_data['Expiry'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

How can I change my code so that my excel should also have date format?

**PS: I don't want datetime format, need only date.**

Comment: You're not changing the date format, you're changing the date into a string, as is clearly specified in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Comment: @BigBen Can you please suggest how should I change the date format then.

Comment: [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) has a `date_format` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_data['Expiry']=pd.to_datetime(new_data['Expiry'], format = '%d-%m-%Y')
new_data['Expiry']=new_data['Expiry'].dt.date
```